# why when i want copy (with memcpy)struct array to char array , character array is null?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char, udp

I want to copy a struct array to a char array with `memcpy` function, but when I do this , char array is null.

1. why data structure can not copy to struct array?
2. why when I want copy (with `memcpy`) struct array to char array, character array is null?

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #include <string.h> 

   using namespace std;

   int main()
   {
      struct group {
          int num=1;
          int age=2;
      };

      struct group a[17];

      int m = sizeof(a);
      char b[200];
      memcpy(&b[0],&a,sizeof(a));

      cout << "Hello World" << n << " " << m << endl << "b='" << b[2] << "'--" << endl;

      return 0;
   }
   ```

output:

```
sh-4.2$ main                                                                                                                                                             
Hello World 136                                                                                                                                                          
b=''--
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you understand how `int` values are stored in memory, or the concept of [*endianness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)? What makes you think that the third by of the array would be something printable?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but, you are copying binary data to a character array.

Your first bytes of binary data will be structured like

> 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000001

Your `b[2]` will contain the 3th byte, which is `0000 0000`, the null character `\0`, typically used to terminate a string.

If you give `num` a different value you'll see it produces a different output. Try `-1` for example.

*note: not doing endian here.*

Answer (score 0):

You're doing a big c++ no-no, by mixing apples and oranges, this causes an overflow of b[] in your call to memcpy() !!!!! In any case, cout::operator<< is right here.  After memcpy(), your array b starts with these bytes, which are not printable characters...

```
01 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 ...
```

So, b[] contains a 1 byte long invalid string.  b[2] == 0, and parts of a[] have been overwritten, and you're lucky you program has not bombed.